# Laravel editing a form, getting value for dropdown lists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

I had a user submit a form, and some of the fields were dropdowns like so

```
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label for="type" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Type</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                      <select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
                        <option>Apartment</option>
                        <option>House</option>
                        <option>Studio</option>
                        <option>Flat</option>
                      </select>
                      @if ($errors->has('type'))
                          <span class="invalid-feedback">
                              <strong>{{ $errors->first('type') }}</strong>
                          </span>
                      @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

That works just fine.

I'm no trying to allow users to edit a particular form. I can get other sections like title and photo by assigning a value to the input and calling the data like this

```
<input id="Address" type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="{{$Advert->address }}" required autofocus>
```

But when I attempt to do something similar on a select option, nothing appears. This is a dropdown on the edit page.

```
<div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="type" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-right">Type</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                              <select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type" value="{{$Advert->type}}">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Apartment</option>
                                <option>House</option>
                                <option>Studio</option>
                                <option>Flat</option>
                              </select>
                              @if ($errors->has('type'))
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                      <strong>{{ $errors->first('type') }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `selected` attribute on your `option` element instead of assigning the value directly to `select`:

```
<select class ="form-control" id="type" name="type">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Apartment' ? 'selected':'' }}>Apartment</option>
      <option {{ $Advert->type == 'House' ? 'selected':'' }}>House</option>
      <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Studio' ? 'selected':'' }}>Studio</option>
      <option {{ $Advert->type == 'Flat' ? 'selected':'' }}>Flat</option>
 </select>
```

But I suggest you use [`Laravel Collective Forms`](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html) to have a better handling of form and it's elements

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: How would I do this when the values are not hard coded. I have tried foreach ($Advert->county as $county)
                                  <option {{ $county->name == '{{$county->name}}' ? 'selected':'' }}>{{$county->name}}</option>
                                endforeach

Comment: im not following

Comment: Instead of applying this to hard code values. How would I apply this to data retireved from the db

Comment: You need a list of all selectable values and you need a single selected value, then you do a foreach on the list and compare each value from the list with the single selected value

Answer (score 0):

Like it was suggested before I would use Laravel Collective Forms; like this:

```
{!! Form::select('type',$selectOptions,null,['id' =>'type','class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

The variable $selectOptions would have all the options:

```
$selectOptions = [
    '' => 'Select',
    'Apartment' => 'Apartment',
    'House' => 'House',
    'Studio' => 'Studio',
    'Flat' => 'Flat'
];
```

It will be this easy to do. Offcourse everything should be inside a form.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}} or {!! Form::model($model) !!}
```

Hope it helps.