# laravel - set selected in the html dropdown menu

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a post form that is shared between `create` and `edit` function.

This is my `edit.blade.php`:

```
@extends('posts.create')
@section('editName',$post->name)
@section('editselected',$post->selected)
```

Then, I use `@yield` to get my value:

```
<input name="name" value="@yield('editName')"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title">
```

I can do that with most of the input fields, but I want to do that in the dropdown menu. I tried:

```
<select class="selectpicker" name="myoptions" value="@yield('editselected')">
<option {{ ( @yield('editselected') == '1 hour') ? 'selected' : '' }}>1 hour</option>
<option {{ ( @yield('editselected') == '3 hours') ? 'selected' : '' }}>3 hours</option>
<option {{ ( @yield('editselected') == '5 hours') ? 'selected' : '' }}>5 hours</option>
</select>
```

and get an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

I obviously doing it wrong. But How can I make it work?

**Edit01**
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974219/laravel-editing-a-form-getting-value-for-dropdown-lists?rq=1), the same situation like mine. But they use `variable` instead. May be my question is, how to pass `$variable` to `@yield` ?